# How to count the repeated values in list based on anoth list in karate

Tags: karate

I am count the repeated values from the list

```
[
  "Cloud Services - Hybrid and Azure",
  "Cloud Services - Hybrid and Azure",
  "Cloud Services - Hybrid and Azure",
  "Cloud Services - Hybrid and Azure",
  "Application Development",
  "Application Development",
  "Application Development",
  "CAB Approval"
]
```

and i want the output to be "Cloud Services - Hybrid and Azure" = 4

```
karate.distinct() throws error. any help on this is much appreciated.

I tried to take unique values :
```

- json group = new java.util.HashSet(group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JS array operations, much simpler:

```
* def result = data.filter(x => x == 'Application Development')
* assert result.length == 3
```